# How to pass a function pointer when the pointee has optional parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, function-pointers

I'm trying to pass a function pointer as a parameter of another function, but the function pointer may or may not itself have an argument (making it different from the other questions I searched for).

The code works as is, but MY problem is that I was trying to use a single function and pass in each different function pointer, but what I have below is 3 different functions to pass each function pointer. I'd like to get rid of the 3 different function definitions as they are all the same with the exception of the passed in function pointer (so basically, 3 copies of execute_func() definitions). Here's what I have so far but this doesn't seem right that I should need three execute_func() calls.

```
class A { ... };
class B { ... };

class Test {
    private:
        std::function<void()> fp;
        std::function<void(MyA &)> fp;
        std::function<void(MyB &)> fp;
    // ...
};

// Here I create a function pointer for each of my calls.
Test::Test() {
    fp = std::bind(&Test::do_this, this);
    fp_a = std::bind(&Test::do_a, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    fp_b = std::bind(&Test::do_b, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}

// Here my intention was to have only 1 execute_func() call and I would 
// pass in the pointer to the function that I want to call.
Test::test_it()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    execute_func(fp);
    execute_func(fp_a, a);
    execute_func(fp_b, b);
}

// I was hoping to only need one function, but so far
// have needed 3 functions with diff signatures to make it work.
bool Test::execute_func(std::function<void()> fp) {
    // ... more code here before the fp call
    fp();
    // ... them more common code here.
}

bool Test::execute_func(std::function<void(MyA &)> fp, MyA &a) { 
    // ... more common code here 
    fp(a);
    // ... and more common code here
}

bool Test::execute_func(std::function<void(MyB &)> fp, MyB &b) {  
    // ... more common code here 
    fp(b);
    // ... and more common code here.
}

// And of course the execute_func() calls call these members as passed in.
bool Test::do_this() { ... }
bool Test::do_a(MyA &a) { ... }
bool Test::do_b(MyB &b) { ... }
```

Thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The return type of your `do_*` functions doesn't match the `std::function` that you pass `execute_func`. And in the future, please *tell* us what the problem with code you're showing is. If there are build errors, then include them.

Comment: Do you know about perfect forwarding?

Comment: I've edited to the requested info, hopefully this is a bit more clear. No build errors. I just feel I'm doing it wrong as I shouldn't need 3 execute_func() calls.

Comment: Why do you need `execute_func` at all? You could just do `fp(); fp_a(a); fp_b(b);`.

Comment: @melpomene - No, I do not. Something I should look into?

Comment: @melpomene - I see your point. I simplified too much. The execute_func() call has a bit more info in it that I did not show, I'll try to edit. So my intention was to call one execute_func() call with other code that they all share in common, but then call the passed in function pointer.

Comment: How about `execute_func([&]() { fp_a(a); });` then?

Comment: @melpomene - ok, a lamda. But, it seems I would still need the 3 differing execute_func() calls since there is code before and after each function pointer that needs to be called? (I'm not able to test this till the morning (not at work ATM)).

Comment: What. Are you trying to get rid of the 3 `execute_func` calls or the 3 different `execute_func` definitions?

Comment: Ok, made the edit to explain that more. I'm trying to get rid of the 3 different execute_func() definitions (not the calls), since the definitions are all the same minus the pointer to the function that gets called.

Comment: OK, then my suggestion would be to keep only the `execute_func(std::function<void()> fp)` version and pass `fp_a` bound to `a` in (e.g. by using a lambda).

Comment: Ok. I'll leave a message when I try it in the morning and then you can post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand the question after all this discussion. Do you want a type erased functor with overloaded `operator()`? If so, you'd have to write your own

Comment: I edited the title to be more clear (I hope) -- after all, a function pointer cannot take a parameter, can it? It s admittedly not simple because there are two functions with parameters involved, the one pointed to as well as the one receiving the pointer. Feel free to revert.

Comment: You have three declarations of the data member (not a member function)  `fp`, all with different types. This cannot work. Please create a [mcve] and post it together with all actual compilation errrors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use a [variadic template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
bool Test::execute_func(Ret fp(Args&&...), Args&&... args)
{
    // do stuff
    fp(args...);
    // do more stuff
}
```

I'm using an ordinary function pointer here instead of `std::function`, which is, IMO, baroque and wholly unnecessary (it's a relic from when C++ didn't have lambdas). But it's the same idea.

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
bool Test::execute_func(const std::function<Ret(Args&&...)> &fp, Args&&... args) { }
```

**Edit:** [Jarod42 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171205/how-to-pass-a-function-pointer-when-the-pointee-has-optional-parameters/47173642?noredirect=1#comment81302128_47173642) that you can make it so it will work with both function pointers, `std::function` and any other callable object as follows:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
bool Test::execute_func(Func &&fp, Args&&... args)
{
    // do stuff
    fp(args...);
    // do more stuff
}
```

To make it even more generic you can use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to call `fp` instead of directly calling it, which additionally allows `fp` to be a member function or data member (with the instance pointer given in the first subsequent argument).

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
bool Test::execute_func(Func &&fp, Args&&... args)
{
    // do stuff
    std::invoke(fp, args...);
    // do more stuff
}
```

The previous example could also equivalently be written

```
template<typename... InvokeArgs>
bool Test::execute_func(InvokeArgs&&... iargs)
{
    // do stuff
    std::invoke(iargs...);
    // do more stuff
}
```

Comment: You may even do `template<typename F, typename... Args>
bool Test::execute_func(F&& fp, Args&&... args)`. so it also works for `std::function` as for OP.

Comment: `std::function` is used for type unification, something that lambda's cannot do at all - even identical lambda's have different types! E.g. `std::map<std::string, std::function<Foo(Bar)>` can't be done with lambda's.

Comment: @MSalters to contain then in the map I do agree, but in the function parameter, it's not that useful. You can also constrain the `F&&` template parameter to be convertible into a `std::function` if you want you interface to be strong.